# What happened to my USB flash drive's files and can I prevent it to happen again?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, usb-flash-drive

I'm working on a windows 7 premium 64 bits computer.

I own several USB flash drives. I've recently got a promotional one, when I plugged it on the computer the usual Windows popup that ask what you want to do with the drive (play videos/watch images/open in file explorer/etc.) only showed the open in explorer option, which I picked. What was odd is that instead of directly opening the explorer with the content of the flash drive, Windows opened *My Computer* and I had to open the drive from there. After that, every other flash drive I own got the same behaviour when plugged in and all the file they contained "disappeared". The space on the drive was still used so I guessed that my file were not deleted however I had no way to show them. After a bit of digging arround I found a solution in the following command :

```
attrib -h -r -s /s /d x:\*.*
```

where **x** is the name of the drive. This allowed me to get my files back so my question is what happeend and how can I prevent it ?

Comment: Your "promotional" USB was infected with the "usb hidden file virus".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Comment: I really doubt that given that its was provided by my university. That's still possible but I doubt it.

Comment: Your computer could have already had the virus when you inserted the USB stick. There are many differerent (but similar in effect) viruses with the symptoms and solutions you describe.

Comment: It's probable though highly unlikely, given the fact that any other drive was working properly prior to that. Then again it would have been on the drive but I found nothing suspicious on it and it was empty when given to me.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to scan your computer anyways ...